# How to use vimpulse together with autopair.el

Tags: emacs

It seems that when vimpulse is running, autopair only works partially in the sense that pressing backspace in empty bracket pairs will no longer remove the closing bracket but only the opening one (which means backspace functions as normal backspace now). An example:

(When Vimpulse and autopair are both active, and current mode is INSERT mode, "|" denotes the cursor)

begin: (|)

Now press "backspace"

expected result: | (both opening and closing brackets are removed)

actual result: |) (only the opening bracket is removed)

I know this has to do with the fact that vimpulse (or rather viper-mode) remapped [backspace] from delete-backward-char to something else (viper-delete-backward-char I think). But I could not find a fix to it.

Could anybody find a solution to this? (so that backspace key will remove both opening and closing bracket when the bracket is empty and cursor is in between).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question myself.

I could not figure out an "orthodoxy" way to solve the problem and I came up with a hack.

The function that is bound to  in viper insert mode (viper-del-backward-char-in-insert) is adviced to check whether cursor is currently in a matched pair, if so, the character after the cursor is deleted before the actual  function is called. This also takes into account possible problem caused by prefix character (backslash).

Just copy the code below into your .emacs file after viper-mode or vimpulse is loaded.

```
(defun not-escaped (escape-char)

  "Character immediately before cursor is not prefixed by escape-char"
  (let ((count 0))
    (save-excursion
      (if (char-before)
          (backward-char))
      (while (and (char-before)
                  (= (char-before) escape-char))
        (setq count (+ count 1))
        (backward-char))
      (if (= 0
             (% count 2))
          t
        nil))))

(defun in-matched-empty-pair (pair-list)
  "tell if cursor is in an empty pair in pair-list"
  (let ((next-char (char-after))
        (prev-char (char-before))
        (matched nil)
        (pair)
        (pair-left)
        (pair-right))
    (if (and next-char
             prev-char)
          (while (and (setq pair
                       (pop pair-list))
                      (not matched))
            (setq pair-left (pop pair)
                  pair-right (pop pair))
            (if (= next-char pair-right)
                (if (and
                     (= prev-char pair-left)
                     (not-escaped ?\\))
                    (setq matched t)))))
    (if matched
        t
      nil)))

(defvar viper-workaround-pairs
      '(
        (?\" ?\")
        (?\' ?\')
        (?\` ?\`)
        (?\( ?\))
        (?\[ ?\])
        (?\{ ?\})
        ))

;; Workaround for integration problem with autopair
(defadvice viper-del-backward-char-in-insert (before viper-auto-delete-pair-backward())
  (if (in-matched-empty-pair viper-workaround-pairs)
      (delete-char 1)))

;; Activate advice
(ad-activate 'viper-del-backward-char-in-insert)
```

This is a hack but it is probably the best I could do now.

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this in your init file would work:

```
(add-hook 'autopair-mode-hook 
  '(lambda ()
    (define-key autopair-emulation-alist [remap viper-delete-backward-char] 'autopair-backspace)))
```

Comment: Thanks jtahlborn, but it doesn't work. Firstly autopair-emulation-alist is not a keymap and thus this causes error. Thus I tried to hack into autopair.el and add (define-key map [remap viper-delete-backward-char] 'autopair-backspace) in the autopair keymap. Still no luck.

Comment: @xyc0562 - after you did that, was the delete key bound to the "autopair-backspace" method?

Comment: @ jtahlborn - It has always been bound to <backspace> and "DEL", as the "describe-function" shows. But the problem is, neither <backspace> nor "DEL" works as expected if vimpulse is on

Comment: so, you are saying that the delete key binding _is_ changed by autopair mode, but it is not behaving as expected?  if so, i don't have any ideas.  i actually disabled that functionality in autopair because it was not functioning correctly for me either, and i don't use vimpulse mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated solution. Put the following in your .emacs file **after** the code that loads autopair and vimpulse:

```
(add-to-ordered-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists (car (last emulation-mode-map-alists)) 400)
```

It moves autopair's keymap in front of viper's one, giving it higher priority.
Maybe you have to adept the order number (here `400`), depending on whether you are using additional emulation-modes.
The result can be checked with `C-x v emulation-mode-map-alists`. In my case:

```
(viper--intercept-key-maps cua--keymap-alist autopair-emulation-alist viper--key-maps)
```

Now, `autopair-emulation-alist` should be listed before `viper--key-maps`.

Comment: Thanks, baumichel, this does work immediately after evaluation. But the problem is, every time I switch to Command Mode and back to Insert mode, it doesn't work any more. Perhaps we need to add some hooks or advice some Viper or Vimpulse function to make it work? I tried some of them, but none works.

Comment: Hi xyc0562. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

baumichel found the trick. I just add a quick snippet to help :

First, as `autopair-mode` simply appends `autopair-emulation-alist`, evaluate:

```
(defadvice viper-change-state-to-insert (after autopair nil activate)
  (add-to-ordered-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists 'autopair-emulation-alist 300))
```

Then, remember that `vimpulse-normalize-minor-mode-map-alist` removes all `viper` keymaps in front of the alist, so execute:

```
(defadvice vimpulse-normalize-minor-mode-map-alist (after order-viper--key-maps nil activate)
   (add-to-ordered-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists 'viper--key-maps 500))
```

That works for me! I evaluate these snippets in an embedded `eval-after-load` for both `vimpulse` and `autopair`.

My idea is that Emacs dev should rethink the `emulation-mode-map-alists` and use a property list indexing priority order like this: `((:name viper--key-maps :after (cua--keymap-alist autopair-emulation-alist)) (:name viper--intercept-key-maps :before (cua--keymap-alist autopair-emulation-alist)))`. Old packages like `viper`, `CUA` and so on should be better maintained because our setup becomes ugly after years with Emacs.